# Find the process id of a java application in a bash script (to see if the target application is already running)

Tags: bash, shell-script, java, process-management, bash-script

I know there are a million questions on getting the process ID, but this one seems to be unique. Google has not given me the answer, so I hope stackexhange will help rather than close this question.

When Java is involved it seems trickier to find a process ID (pgrep doesn't work afaik).

Furthermore, I need to automate this in a bash script. One issue I've encountered is that when I use `ps aux | grep` the grep process itself always shows up, so handling the results in a simple bash script is not trivial enough for me to figure out a good solution on my own (with my limited bash skills).

Some things I have tried:

Example 1 - this returns a process even though there is no application by that name:

```
$ ps aux | grep -i anythingnotreal
user2   3040  0.0  0.0   4640   856 pts/3    S+   18:17   0:00 grep --color=auto -i anythingnotreal
```

Example 2 - this returns nothing even though "java_app" is currently running:

```
$ pgrep java_app
```

It returns nothing. However, here's proof that "java_app" is running:

```
$ ps aux | grep java_app
tester2   2880  0.7  2.8 733196 58444 ?        Sl   18:02   0:07 java -jar /opt/java_app2/my_java_app.jar
tester2   3058  0.0  0.0   4644   844 pts/3    S+   18:19   0:00 grep --color=auto java_app
```

What I need is a solution I can plug into a bash script that will tell me if the java application of interest (for which I know the jar file name and path) is currently running. (If it is running, I need to ask the user to close it before my script continues.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

By default, `pgrep` only matches the command, not the arguements. To match the full command line, you need the `-f` option.

```
$ pgrep -f java_app
```

From the pgrep manpage:

> -f The pattern is normally only matched against the process name. When -f is set, the full command line is used

Comment: Thanks. It works and it is very easy to use (and remember).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pidof java` to figure out what java processes are running and then get the detail of each process such as `ps -p $PID -o pid,vsz=MEMORY -o user,group=GROUP -o comm,args=ARGS`, then you can determine if target application is running and it usage whether need to ask user to close or continue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jcmd](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/tooldescr006.html) utility that's part of the JDK. It only lists currently running Java processes, so all you need to do is grep for `java_app`

```
jcmd | grep java_app | cut -d " " -f 1
```